# DependecyProperty Updated twice

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties

As the title says, I have a `DependencyProperty` on a `UserControl`, which is of the type `IEnumerable` of  an `Interface`, making my `DependecyProperty` look like this:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemSourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ItemSource", typeof(IEnumerable<IPerson>), typeof(PersonListUserControl), new PropertyMetadata(ChangedValue));
public IEnumerable<IPerson> ItemSource
{
   get { return (IEnumerable<IPerson>)GetValue(ItemSourceProperty); }
   set { SetValue(ItemSourceProperty, value); }
}
```

This `IEnumerable` is used as `ItemsSource` for an `ItemsControl`, but what I've experienced is that this collection, in the finally call to the `ChangedValue` method, defined in the `DependecyProperty` is `NULL`.

```
private static void ChangedValue(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var uc = d as PersonListUserControl;
    if (uc != null)
    {
       var oldValue = (IEnumerable<IPerson>) e.OldValue;
       var newValue = (IEnumerable<IPerson>)e.NewValue;
    }
 }
```

This UserControl is used in an Window, and defined like this:

```
<personUserControl:PersonListUserControl ItemSource="{Binding PersonCollection}"/>
```

Does anybody have a good solution?

**As Requested here is the `XAML` code for the `UserControl` where my DP is used**

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ItemSource, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"
                              ItemTemplate="{Binding Path=TemplateDefinition, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"/>
```

Comment: Do you mean that it is updated twice at startup?

Comment: Yes. The first time, the `oldValue` is NULL, and the `newValue` has one item. The second time this method is also called, which means that the DP is updated -> Now `oldValue` has one item, but the `newValue` is NULL.

Comment: When and where is "PersonCollection" used? Put a breakpoint in the getter (and setter, if present) for the property, so you can trace calls and see what triggers the change

Comment: @WillemvanRumpt Yes, I've done so, but the setter is of the "PersonCollection" is just called once, when I initalize the List and add an item in the constructor.

Comment: How is `ItemSource` used inside your UserControl? You might show that XAML or code, too. Also, it might make sense to rename the property to the more common name `ItemsSource` (with `s`).

Comment: ...was going to be my next comment :)

Comment: Looks ok. Are you sure there isn't any other code that resets the property?

Comment: @Clemens Since the UserControl is so lightweight I'm quite sure.

Comment: I remember seeing this kind of behavior, but unfortunately I do not have the affected code infront of me.. But I do remember troubleshooting it by checking the call stack for the different calls. From where do the calls come from? If you have visual studio, make sure that you enable external code in the call stack window. I think that could help to post

Comment: @Default Most calls comes from WindowsBase.dll and PresentationFramework.dll - Which indicates that none of my code updates the DependencyProperty to Null, I guess.